# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean

Tags: php

Been deploying this code fine for months, years but today its returning an issue.

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean

Understood, but why is it returning `true` ?

Code:

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=...", $username, $password);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table")->execute()->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 3):

`execute()` doesn't return the result of the query, it returns a boolean that indicates whether the query was successful. You need to call `fetchColumn()` on the `PDOStatement` object that `prepare()` returneds.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```